# How to remove languages in iTunes Store App description

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store

My app is intended to only support English, however there are a few libraries I am using that include within localization.strings file which xCode picked up and placed in the "Localizations" settings of the "Info" section for my Project settings.

I forgot to delete these localizations, and now my app shows up in iTunes Store App description as supporting these languages, when I do not want this displayed as such.

Is there some way I can remove these languages from the iTunes Store App description when my app is already live in the app store?

This is how it appears in iTunes Store:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

When you have a language that is missing translation you get a warning sign beside each language on the drop down menu. If you hover over the languages on the drop down table, a delete button will appear at the right of the hovered table row:
[image]
If you click on the delete button on the right you will get this confirmation warning:
[image]

It easy to find in hindsight, but I did struggle to find on my own. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 5):

It seems I was using a library called nsdatetimeago that had bundled with it many .lproj folders for each language.

iTunes Connect automatically looks for the localizations that you have set in your "Localizations" section under your Project settings.

Since I am using this libarary, my Project settings had listed all those languages in the "localizations" section.

I removed those unwanted languages and following app releases were correctly seen via iTunes Store.

Answer (score -2):

Xcode > Your Project > Info > Localizations

Before uploading the application, you need to remove unnecessary languages.