# Is there any way to remove particular language from app store in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, localization

I have multiple language in my resource folder like english,french,spanish and portuguese so I want when I upload apps to app store then in language description it shows only three languages english,french,spanish not portuguese.
How we can restrict particular language in Xamarin.ios without removing the language support from resource folder.
Thanks

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321482/how-to-remove-languages-in-itunes-store-app-description .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have gone through the above link what you mentioned in that in app store we can remove the particular languages but you have any idea from application we can restrict the languages.

Comment: if build action set to none for particular file in resource folder that way can we exclude in app store.

Comment: Nawnit were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @Saamer not able to figure it out still I am looking for solution.

Comment: I don't think you can implement it . It depends on the configuration on your app.