# How can I disable the english language of my app without deleting my localizable.strings?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, localization

I just tried to localize an app for the first time. I've added localizable.strings for the english and german language, both of them in their own .lproj folder. In info.plist I also added "localization native development region" with value "de" and "localizations" with values "de" and "en".  Everything works fine but I want to keep my app in german for the beginning.

How can I disable the english language now? I thought I'd only need to remove it from the info.plist in "localizations" but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: Do you want to remove English language from app store ? You could check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321482/how-to-remove-languages-in-itunes-store-app-description

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I don't think this is the same problem that I have. I basically want to keep everything that I have right now, but only disable the english translation that I've written. So no matter what the user has selected as his default language, german will be the app language. But when I enable english again, I want users that have english as their default language to see english text.

Comment: So you want to set the default language as german in your app , right ? If so , you just need to set the `NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey(NSArray.FromStrings("xxx"), new NSString("AppleLanguages"));
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronize();`

Comment: I think I already have set the default language to german in my app by adding "localize native development region" with value of "de" in info.plist. But I want the app to be in german all the time now. I dont want the user to be able to see any other language than german. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: I guess that would be one option but was trying to find another one :( Thats why I asked (in the title of this question) whether there is another way, without deleting all my folders with the localizable.strings

Comment: If you do want to keep it , you could rename it as a provisional string(wrong name will not work) and set it as correct format when you want to display the option . .